# "Которых" или "которые"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно:

1) в поисках моментов, которые не замечают другие
2) в поисках моментов, которых не замечают другие

Вроде и схожие темы уже прочла, но все равно не уверена.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

В поисках моментов, **которых** не замечают другие.

Родительный падеж при отрицании заменяет винительный **по общему правилу**.

Использование формы В. п. "которые" может сделать структуру предложения неясной (повтор одинаковых форм "которые, другие").

Пример:

И он ...обвиняет меня в невежестве, называет термины, **которых** не знает... [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)].

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно:
>
> 1) *В поисках моментов, **которые не замечают другие**.*
>
> 2) *В поисках моментов, **которых не замечают другие**.*

Я бы выбрал или **первый**, или какой-либо из этих вариантов:

*В поисках моментов, **которые не замечаются другими.***

*В поисках моментов, **не замечаемых другими.***

Answer (score -1):

С точки зрения выбора падежа оба варианта возможны, но фраза стилистически неудачна по другим причинам.

В целом я за вариант с винительным падежом, но с небольшим уточнением контекста:
*В поисках моментов, которые не замечают другие **люди*** (или кто там еще по мысли автора).

===========================

Грамматически при выборе падежа возможен любой из вариантов. Но по контексту - оба неудачны. Первый, поскольку получается, что это моменты не замечают, а второй вызавает ощущения согласования по падежу со словом "моментов".

Другими словами, надо бы уточнить:

*В поисках моментов, которых не замечают другие авторы (следователи, ученые...).*
Или
*В поисках моментов, которые не замечают другие люди (работы, художники...).*

Таким образом, грамматика придаточного:

*Другие авторы (подлежащее) не замечают (сказуемое) которых[=моментов]/которые[=моменты].*

И вот тогда вопрос, "не замечают моментов", или "не замечают моменты"?
Ответ зависит от стиля (считается, что научный тяготеет к родительному, а бытовой - к винительному, но бывает и наоборот), но прежде всего от конкретности (определенности) объекта.

Вот здесь есть достаточно полный список случаев, когда требуется тот или иной падеж 
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67
Прямого указания на наш случай нету, то есть допускаются оба варианта, но по сути рекомендаций видно, что чем определеннее дополнение, тем сильнее тяга к винительному.

Особенно вот эти два.

> При наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на определенность
>   объекта: Эту песню не задушишь, не убьешь; он не решил эту задачу
>   (ср.: он не решал задач); Ростов, не желая навязывать свое знакомство,
>   не пошел в дом (Л. Толст.).
>
> При наличии после существительного
>   придаточного предложения со словом который: Он не прочитал книгу,
>   которую я ему дал.

Буквы закона тут нет, у нас другая структура предложения, но по духу - самое оно.  У нас то же слово "который", только в обратной функции по отношению к интересующему слову.

Да, еще важно то, что глагол с отрицанием здесь не относится к группе "ждательных" - тех, которые вообще склонны управлять прямым дополнением в родительном падеже даже без отрицания ("ждать" и некоторые другие, выражающие чувства) или "знательных", тяготеющих к управлению родительным именно при отрицании в любом контексте ("знать", "понимать" и подобные).

Отсюда и такое:

> И он ...обвиняет меня в невежестве, называет термины, которых не
>   знает... [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок

- замените "знает" на "объясняет", "принимает" и т. п. и пример как аргумент рассыпается.  **Называет термины, которые не объясняет** - иное воспринимается едва ли не как просторечие. **Называет термины, которые не использует** - а тут кому-то родительный показался бы возможным?

Подробнее тут.
https://books.google.ru/books?id=_6ZCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#v=onepage&q=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false